# roswtf service malfunctioning error

Tags: ros, namespace, ros-kinetic, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I have been experimenting with namespaces for my two turtlebot3s. Everything seemed to be fine when I launched and sshed, but when I went to run some gmapping code, I noticed I was missing some nodes in view_frames for my 2nd bot. This only happens when I run the bringup remote.launch code from a launch script that automatically ssh's into the bot. If I manually ssh and run the remote.launch, these errors do not manifest. When I ran roswtf, I discovered the following errors. I've already double checked the  IP addresses and ros_master_uri. Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this? Thank you!
The launch file:

```
<launch>
    <!-- Robot1 -->
    <!-- may need to remove ns from group tag-->
    <group ns="bot1">
        <machine name="bot1" address="10.1.xxx.xx" user="user" password="password" default="true" env-loader="~/catkin_ws/devel/env.sh"/>
        <node pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py" name="turtlebot3_core" output="screen">
            <param name="tf_prefix" value="bot1_tf" />
            <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyACM0"/>
            <param name="baud" value="115200"/>
        </node>
        <node pkg="hls_lfcd_lds_driver" type="hlds_laser_publisher" name="turtlebot3_lds" output="screen">
            <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>
            <param name="frame_id" value="/bot1_tf/base_scan"/>
            <param name="tf_prefix" value="bot1_tf" />
        </node>
        <node pkg="turtlebot3_bringup" type="turtlebot3_diagnostics" name="turtlebot3_diagnostics" output="screen">
            <param name="tf_prefix" value="bot1_tf" />
        </node>
    </group>
</launch>
```

The errors:

```
ERROR The following nodes should be connected but arent:
 * /bot1/turtlebot3_diagnostics->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /bot1/turtlebot3_lds->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /bot1/turtlebot3_core->/rosout (/rosout)

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/bot1/turtlebot3_core/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/bot1/turtlebot3_core/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://turtlebot:37186]
 * service [/bot1/turtlebot3_lds/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/bot1/turtlebot3_lds/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://turtlebot:34368]
 * service [/bot1/turtlebot3_lds/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/bot1/turtlebot3_lds/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://turtlebot:34368]
 * service [/bot1/turtlebot3_core/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/bot1/turtlebot3_core/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://turtlebot:37186]
 * service [/bot1/turtlebot3_diagnostics/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/bot1/turtlebot3_diagnostics/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://turtlebot:51942]
 * service [/bot1/turtlebot3_diagnostics/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/bot1/turtlebot3_diagnostics/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://turtlebot:51942]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298898/roswtf-service-malfunctioning-error/) by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-29**:
So a `ping turtlebot` works? On *all* involved hosts?

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-29**:
@gvdhoorn yes, I was even able to run tele-op on it!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-31**:
You write that you "checked all IP addresses", but have you also configured either `ROS_IP` or `ROS_HOSTNAME` with the correct values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case, this was due to network configuration. I had my turtlebotbots all named the same thing in the /etc/hosts file on my remote pc. Changing those names to something unique, and then doing the same in the turtlebot’s /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname files fixed the problem.

---

Originally posted by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) with karma: 95 on 2018-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0